# MySql update statement for a binary file not updating

Tags: java, mysql

ok, the below statement works with there wasnt a row  create. and in my code i push a file into my database with binary stream and in the code below you see this, and it works but i need it to update a row instead of insert, how would i do that?

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.showOpenDialog(this);
    File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
    File j = f;
    //String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
    //picPreview.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
    try{
     BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(j);
     BufferedImage scaled = getScaledInstance(
     image, picPreview.getWidth(), picPreview.getHeight(), RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR, true);
     picPreview.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaled));
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
    try{
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
        int len = (int)f.length();

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newbieswithauctions","root","root");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO listings(itemPicture) VALUES(?)");
        ps.setBinaryStream(1, fin, len);
        int status = ps.executeUpdate();
        if(status>0){
            jLabel2.setText("Successfully uploaded image to database");
        }
        else{
            jLabel2.setText("Upload Failed!");
        }
    }catch(Exception e )
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e, "Error ",        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

i tried to put VALUES(?) and i used a variable i had but i failed miserably

```
"UPDATE listings SET itemPicture=VALUES(?) WHERE itemVin='" + VinNum + "'");
```

Comment: Whats this `VALUES(?)` and what error are you getting? Post your stacktrace.

Comment: Use `UPDATE listings SET itemPicture=? WHERE itemVin=?` and call `setBinaryStream(1, fin, len)` and `setString(2, VinNum)`. *Never* use string concatenation to insert text in a SQL statement, or you'll run into syntax issues and [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities.